# .htcaccess script

Tags: string, .htaccess

So I'm having this (hopefully simple) problem with my profile page.

Currently, the link is `http://sound-booth.com/profile/?id=1`

With the help of a .htcaccess file, I'd like to make the link look like this: `http://sound-booth.com/profile?id=1`

The problem is, I don't know an ounce of .htcaccess. Mind sparing a minute to help me out?

Answer (score 0):

It would have to be `http://sound-booth.com/profile/someFile.html?id=1` because you are missing the final part of the url before the `?`. It must be defaulting to index.html or home.html or something.

Comment: It actually is. I saved it under index.php to try and see if it would change to what I wanted it to be. I don't want the file name showing nor the type of file it is, thats why I was relying on .htcaccess